# Creating geojson-vt with qgis project?

Tags: qgis, wfs

Qgis project can be published as WMS service ,WFS service etc.

But any library is there to create geojson-vt which will be equivalent to wfs

Comment: geoserver can serve geojson as a WFS format, but what is geojson-vt?

Comment: -vt for vector tiles . to reduce data exchange size..

Comment: please edit your question to clarify it